# Losing filesystem after creating a partition with fdisk

Tags: partitioning, grub2, filesystem, fdisk

I created a partition with `fdisk` and after writing the change to the disk and reboot, I got stuck at Grub and lost my filesystem on the disk. What happened and do I have the chance to backup my data ?

Comment: Backups are done *before* situations like this. RE: What happened we don't and can't know. We can only speculate that you created a partition on the existing ones instead of alongside (after).

Comment: Run this report just to see configuration, not to make any repairs. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair